# SQL / HiveQL multiple aggregates from same window

Tags: sql, hadoop, optimization, hive, query-optimization

I would like to know if there are tricks to optimizing the following HiveQL (or SQL, out of curiosity).

For example, if I have a table:

```
   x   |   y   |   e   |   time
   2   |   5   |   1   | 11:30:00
   2   |   1   |   1   | 12:15:00
   8   |   0   |   1   | 16:00:00
   10  |   6   |   2   | 16:06:00
   1   |   2   |   2   | 17:00:00
```

and I want to get multiple aggregates:

```
select
e,
time,
sum(x) over w as cumu_x 
sum(y) over w as cumu_y 
count(x) over w as num_x
from my_table
window w as
(partition by e
 order by time
 rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

should give me the desired result

```
   e   |   time   |   cumu_x   |   cumu_y   |   num_x
   1   | 11:30:00 |     2      |     5      |     1
   1   | 12:15:00 |     4      |     6      |     2
   1   | 16:00:00 |     12     |     6      |     3
   2   | 16:06:00 |     10     |     6      |     1
   2   | 17:00:00 |     11     |     8      |     2
```

**The question**: how can this be optimized? Such Hive queries are extremely slow when millions of rows are involved.

If I were looping over the data myself, I would:

- Calculate all aggregates in the same loop. *Does this happen if I use the window alias?*
- Sort the data once and keep running totals. This is because I know that at each iteration, the result will just be an increment of the prior result. *Does Hive do this? Is there a way to give hints so that it will?*
- Process different bins of "e" in parallel. *Does Hive do this? I only see a single reducer when I run. Is there a way to help Hive parallelize?*

Comment: i think cross join is not correct approach it will have performance hit .Use window function with all sum and e .

Comment: @sandeeprawat could you explain what you mean? I have no join in my SQL that I can see.. (I am new to Hive)

Comment: My bad on window  clause.....